Solving the Bring quintic using the Ramanujan $g$- and $G$-functions?
Ramanujan defined two functions now called the Ramanujan g- and G-functions. One of the more well-known values is,
$$g_{58} = \sqrt{\tfrac{5+\sqrt{29}}2}$$
If we let,
$$2^6\big(g_{58}^{12}+g_{58}^{-12}\big)^2 = 396^4$$
then this appears in his famous formula,
$$\frac1{\pi} = \frac{32\sqrt{2}}{396^2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(4k)!}{(k!)^4}\frac{(58\times455k+1103)}{\color{blue}{396^{4k}}}$$
It turns out we can also use the Ramanujan g- and G-functions to solve the Bring quintic.

I. Definitions
Given the complete elliptic integral of the first kind $K(k)$, the elliptic modulus $k = \dfrac{\vartheta_2^2(0,q)}{\vartheta_3^2(0,q)},\,$ nome $q=e^{\pi i \tau}$, and Dedekind eta function $\eta(\tau)$. Ramanujan preferred $G_n$ for odd $n$ while $g_n$ for even $n$, but we may define them more generally with argument $\tau,$
\begin{align}
G(\tau) &= q^{-\frac{1}{24}}\prod_{n=1}(1+q^{2n-1}) =2^{-1/4}\,\frac{\eta^2(\tau)}{\eta\big(\tfrac{\tau}{2}\big)\eta(2\tau)}\\[5pt]
g(\tau) &= q^{-\frac{1}{24}}\prod_{n=1}(1-q^{2n-1}) = 2^{-1/4}\,\frac{\eta\big(\tfrac{\tau}{2}\big)}{\eta(\tau)}
\end{align}
The example was just $g(\sqrt{-10})=\sqrt{\tfrac{5+\sqrt{29}}2}$. Note that these are closely related to the Weber modular functions. There are relations between $(G,g,k)$ such as,
$$(G^8-g^8)\,(G\,g)^8=\tfrac14$$
$$4G^{24}=(k^2-k^4)^{-1}$$
$$2g^{12}=(k^{-1}-k)\;$$
These will be useful in the proof later.

II. Modular equation
We borrow insights from Hermite's method. He used a different modular equation, but the sextic modular equation between $G(\tau)$ and $G(5\tau)$ was also known to Ramanujan and is quite aesthetic,
$$\frac{u^3}{v^3}+\frac{v^3}{u^3}-2u^2v^2+\frac2{u^2v^2}=0\tag1$$
while that between $g(\tau)$ and $g(5\tau)$ differs only by sign,
$$\frac{u^3}{v^3}-\frac{v^3}{u^3}+2u^2v^2+\frac2{u^2v^2}=0\tag2$$
For the first, if $v = G(\tau)$, the $6$ roots $u$ are,
$$u = G(5\tau),\;\; G(\tau/5),\;-G\big(\tfrac{\tau+24}5\big),\; G\big(\tfrac{\tau+48}5\big),\;-G\big(\tfrac{\tau+72}5\big),\;G\big(\tfrac{\tau+96}5\big)$$
For the second, if $v = g(\tau)$, the $6$ roots $u$ are,
$$u = -g(5\tau),\;\; g(\tau/5),\;\; -g\big(\tfrac{\tau+24}5\big),\;\; g\big(\tfrac{\tau+48}5\big),\;\; -g\big(\tfrac{\tau+72}5\big),\;\; g\big(\tfrac{\tau+96}5\big)\quad$$
(Note: In Hermite's method, it is multiples of $16$.) Define,
$$H(\tau) = \frac1{G^3(\tau)}\Big(G(5\tau)\,+\,G(\tau/5)\Big) \left(G\big(\tfrac{\tau+24}{5}\big)-G\big(\tfrac{\tau+96}{5}\big)\right) \left(G\big(\tfrac{\tau+48}{5}\big)-G\big(\tfrac{\tau+72}{5}\big)\right)$$
$$h(\tau) \,=\, \frac1{g^3(\tau)}\Big(g(5\tau)\,-\,g(\tau/5)\Big) \, \left(g\big(\tfrac{\tau+24}{5}\big)-g\big(\tfrac{\tau+96}{5}\big)\right) \, \left(g\big(\tfrac{\tau+48}{5}\big)-g\big(\tfrac{\tau+72}{5}\big)\right)$$
These will be used to solve the Bring quintic.

III. Solution of quintic
A. Using Ramanujan's $G$-function
Let $H(\tau)$ be defined by $G(\tau)$ as above. Then for $n = (0,1,2,3,4)$,
$$x^5\color{red}{+}5x-c=0$$
$$x_n= \sqrt{H(\tau+16n)}$$
$$\tau =\frac{K'(k)}{K(k)}\sqrt{-1} \,=\, \frac{_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,1,\,1-k^2\big)}{_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,1,k^2\big)}\sqrt{-1}$$
$$k = \sqrt{\frac12+\frac{c\,\sqrt{-c^2+\sqrt{c^4+256}}}{16\sqrt2}}$$
or $k$ is any appropriate root of the $\color{blue}{octic}$,
$$256k^8 - 512k^6 + (384 + c^4)k^4 - (128 + c^4)k^2 + 16=0$$
This is the same octic in Fiedler's method using Jacobi theta $\vartheta_3(0,q)$ in this recent MO post. (Why?)
B. Using Ramanujan's $g$-function
Let $h(\tau)$ be defined by $g(\tau)$ as above. Then for $n = (0,1,2,3,4)$,
$$x^5\color{red}{-}5x-c=0$$
$$x_n= \sqrt{h(\tau+16n)}$$
$$\tau =\frac{K'(k)}{K(k)}\sqrt{-1}$$
and $k$ (in trigonometric and radical form),
$$k =\tan\left(\frac14\arcsin\Big(\frac{16}{c^2}\Big)\right)$$
$$k =\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}\,c-\sqrt{c^2+\sqrt{c^4-256}}}{\sqrt{2}\,c+\sqrt{c^2+\sqrt{c^4-256}}}}$$
or any appropriate root of the $\color{blue}{quartic}$,
$$k^4+\left(\tfrac{c}2\right)^2 k^3+2k^2-\left(\tfrac{c}2\right)^2 k+1 =0$$
This same quartic has now appeared four times, including Hermite's and Fiedler's method using $\vartheta_4(0,q)$ in the same MO post above. (Why?)

IV. Proof
Expand the expressions below with the correct signs,
$$\prod_{n=0}^4\Big(x-\sqrt{H(\tau+16n)}\Big) = 0$$
$$\prod_{n=0}^4\Big(x-\sqrt{h(\tau+16n)}\Big) = 0$$
and we get the simple Bring forms,
$$x^5\color{red}{+}5x-\sqrt8\,\frac{2g^8(\tau)-G^8(\tau)}{G^2(\tau)}=0$$
$$x^5\color{red}{-}5x-\sqrt8\,\frac{g^8(\tau)-2G^8(\tau)}{g^2(\tau)}=0$$
For the first quintic, simply equate its constant term to the constant term $c$ of a generic Bring and, using the relations in Section I, we have $3$ equations in $3$ unknowns $(G,g,k)$,
$$\sqrt8\,\frac{2g^8-G^8}{G^2}= \,c$$
$$(G^8-g^8)\,(G\,g)^8=\tfrac14$$
$$4G^{24}=(k^2-k^4)^{-1}$$
It is a routine matter to solve this system, resulting in the octic in $k$. For the second quintic,
$$\sqrt8\,\frac{g^8-2G^8}{g^2}= \,c$$
$$(G^8-g^8)\,(G\,g)^8=\tfrac14$$
$$2g^{12}=(k^{-1}-k)$$
resulting in the quartic in $k$, and which explains how the elliptic modulus $k$ was found.

V. Question
How do we explain why the same quartic in $k$ has appeared four times now: when using the elliptic lambda $\lambda(\tau)$, Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction $R(q)$, Jacobi theta $\vartheta_4(0,q)$, and the Ramanujan g-function $g(\tau)$? (The first three are in post 1, post 2, and post 3.)
Likewise, the same octic in $k$ has appeared two times now: for  Jacobi $\vartheta_3(0,q)$ and Ramanujan G-function $G(\tau)$. Are there two methods missing ?

Great questions! Could series expansions of these functions at well chosen points give clues?
